# How can I export an iphone screen recording without sound?

Tags: iphone, audio

I used the screen recording function on my iPhone to capture a short clip. The clip also includes the audio of a podcast I was listening to when I was making the recording.

The clip is synced from my phone to the Photo app on my Mac Book Pro.

Now I want to export the clip from my Mac in order to send it to someone else. I don't want to include the the audio from the podcast. How can I remove the audio from the exported mov file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Edit and tap the speaker icon to mute the clip. You can do this on the phone or computer.

When you export it, the sound should not be included. You can confirm this by opening it in QuickTime. There will be no volume slider.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is on your MacBook Pro using Quicktime Player: open .mov file with it, on menubar Edit > Remove Audio.